# Laravel leftJoin and count issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, left-join

This code returns "**count**" and "**odds**" values exactly same (They should not be same). 
It actually only counts the "**o.id**" and returns the same value for both.

How can I count "b.id" correctly?

```
    \DB::table('matches as m')
  ->selectRaw('     m.id as match_id, 
                    m.date_hour as date, 
                    m.tournament_id as tournament_id,
                    h.name as host_name, 
                    g.name as guest_name, 
                    COUNT(o.id) as odds,
                    COUNT(b.id) as count
                     ')
  ->whereRaw('DATE(m.date_hour) = DATE(NOW())') //OK 
  ->leftJoin('teams as h','h.id','=','m.host_id')
  ->leftJoin('teams as g','g.id','=','m.guest_id')
  ->leftJoin('odds as o','o.match_id','=','m.id')
  ->leftJoin('bets as b','b.match_id','=','m.id') 
  ->groupBy('m.id')
  ->having('odds','>','0')
  ->get();
```

Comment: Please post the structure of the used database tables and some examples of what you want exactly.

Comment: @Jerodev I have tables: **matches** , **odds** with match_id, and **bets** with match_id. I would like to get matches listed with odd and bet counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
COUNT(o.id) as odds,
COUNT(b.id) as count
```

with:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(o.id)) as odds,
COUNT(DISTINCT(b.id)) as count
```

It should work.